# UITableView images from sqlite

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to display different images to the table view. and I stored the image names in sqlite. So I think every time I just need to ask the image name from the database and use

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[@"%@.jpg",[self.arraySonglistInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:picture]]
```

but there are something wrong. What should I do here?
The method is :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

NSInteger picture = [self.database.arrayColumnNames indexOfObject:@"picture"];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[@"%@.jpg",[self.arraySonglistInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:picture]];

return cell;
}
```

The error is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

And there is a warning "Expression result unused" in this line:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[@"%@.jpg",[self.arraySonglistInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:picture]];
```

Comment: We are going to need a bit more to go on. What error did you get? What went wrong? Inside what method did you put that line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is with the NSInteger picture line. That calculation yielded the number 9223372036854775807 when it needed a number between 0 - 2.

Comment: Would you please explain more, cuz I also use this line to get other data from the database, like names, they all go fine.

Comment: Put a break point on that line and check the value for the picture. 9223372036854775807 means NSNotFound for indexOfObject:@"picture".

Comment: I modified the name of "picture", and the error become [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]

Comment: You're getting closer!! You have an array with 3 items. They are in index positions 0, 1, 2. Your method is looking for the item in index position 3. Thats why the error message said 3 is beyond the bounds. Vote for my answer  if I helped.